# how to get data from result set by selecting multiple table record using JDBC?

Tags: java

I am trying to get data using result set from multiple tables which throw exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name.

public void test(String code) {
    String sql = "select * from table1 ,table2 where table1.code = table2.code and table.code='" + code + "'";
    try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("table1.code"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
}
```

using this statement it's work find but it's take more time to every individual column and it's bad practice.

```
select table1.code as code,table1.name as name ....,table2.code as 
tbl2Code,... where table1.code=table2.code;
```

Comment: What exception is thrown, please add the error message/stack trace to the question. Have you tried to execute the sql manually to see that the syntax is correct? Not directly relevant to the error but you should use a prepared statement that takes parameters (see [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)) and regarding the sql you should use proper JOIN syntax

Comment: Please share logs for exact issue, but from the first look, table.code is not the right column name in your query, it should table1 or table2.

Comment: it's work find with this select statement : select table1.code as code  from .... but column are more it's bad practices.

Comment: "it's bad practices" - I'm not sure what you're refering to but often `select * from ...` could be considered a bad practice. In any case if you do `select table1.code as code` the column name in the resultset should be `code` but if you do `select * ` the column names should be as they are in the tables (and if I remember correctly without the table name).